# Setting console position

Tags: java, algorithm, console-application

I am working on a project that draws an X out of multiple x's and the number of x's in a diagonal is given by the user. For example if the number given by the user is 4, it would look like this:

```
X  X
 XX
 XX
X  X
```

I have written a program with a print diagonal method, the problem occurs when I draw the second diagonal because it draws the second diagonal below the first one in the console. It looks like this:

```
X
 X
  X
   X
   X
  X
 X
X
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to set the console line back to the beginning so that I could draw another diagonal from the top. I've looked into System methods but I have not been able to find anything. Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's already been suggested that you avoid the problem, and one of the reasons is that the possibility and method of moving the cursor is system dependent.  Some systems may use ANSI seqences, others might emulate a vt52, vt100 or vt220 mainframe terminal, etc.  And I think it is quite possible the output window in some IDE's may be unable to scroll back (based on codes inserted in the output) at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be better to print all your output into an 2D array, and print it all at the end of your program. I will be much easier than manipulating the console cursor locations.

Of course it's possible to set cursor locations. I think you'd better lookup some ascii characters such as '\b' (backspace) that is used to directly manipulate cursor locations. However, I think array-based solution will be much easier, and **portability** is guaranteed.

Comment: Ok thank you for the suggestion and I will look into those ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution manipulating strings, without moving the cursor on the console.

```
Print_X(4);
```

Output:

```
X  X
 XX 
 XX 
X  X
```

Function:

```
public static void Print_X (int num) {
    String str;
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++) {
        str="";
        for(int n=0;n<num;n++) str += " ";
        str=str.substring(0,i)+'X'+str.substring(i+1); 
        str=str.substring(0,(num-1)-i)+'X'+str.substring(num-i);
        System.out.println(str);
    }        
}
```

Or this shorter function direct to the console output:

```
public static void Print_X (int num) {
    int j,i,dz=num-1;
    for(i=0;i<num;i++,dz-=2) {
        for(j=0;j<num;j++) 
            System.out.print((j==i || j==i+dz)?"X":" ");                        
        System.out.println();
    }        
}
```

Comment: @user2226786 One possible solution to your question.